# Keep adding numbers into an array until a = 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop, do-loops

Hi I'm new to javascript and I'm sorry if my question is silly for you.

This question was solved with the following code:

```js
let arr = [12, 6, 53]

let a
do {
  a = prompt("Enter a number")
  a = Number.parseInt(a)
  arr.push(a)
}

while (a != 0)

console.log(arr)
```

But, if I want that run the code if `a == 0` rather than `a != 0`
i simply changed

```
while (a != 0)
```

into

```
while (a == 0)
```

But, it simply adds the number into the array

[image: The problem]

Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

I was expecting that the output should keep asking me to enter a number until a is equal to 0.
I'm a bit silly (Please explain me if I'm right or wrong) I think that running the code until a != 0 and a == 0 should give the same answer in this code

Comment: "*I was expecting that the output should keep asking me to enter a number until a is equal to 0*" the condition `while (a == 0)` implies "do this code while `a` is equal to zero" which is *the opposite* of your intention. "until X" is "while not X". Moreover, it's not reasonable to assume that the inverse of a logical comparison is going to be the same as the logical comparison itself. It happens some times with type juggling and such but simply put since `a` is a number then you expect something like `1 == 0` to be the same as `1 != 0`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, stop using `do..while`. Its usages are very limited and 0.01% of use cases where it actually makes sense are simply not worth the trouble of having yet another syntax construct in your codebase.

In your case, the use of `do` is not justified, because you want to check the condition (`a!=0`) before you perform the action (`arr.push`), not after it. The right pattern here is "loop forever + break":

```
while (true) {
    let a = prompt("Enter a number")
    a = Number.parseInt(a)
    if (a !== 0) {
        break
    }
    arr.push(a)
}
```

Also note that 1) block-scoped variables belong inside the block, not outside it and 2) declaration without initialization (as in `let a;`) is a code smell and should be avoided.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> **Can anyone please explain why this is happening?**
>
> I was expecting that the output should keep asking me to enter a
> number until a is equal to 0. I'm a bit silly (Please explain me if
> I'm right or wrong) I think that running the code until a != 0 and a
> == 0 should give the same answer in this code.

---

```
a != 0
```

Add items to the array if they **do not equal** 0 *(else stop)*

```
a == 0
```

Add items to the array if they **equal** 0 *(else stop)*

---

If you do not want the numbers that do not match adding to the array, then you need to also check this condition before inserting the value (before `push`).

```js
let arr = [12, 6, 53];
let a;

do {
  a = prompt("Enter a number");
  a = Number.parseInt(a);
  if (a == 0) {
    arr.push(a)
  };
}
while (a == 0);

console.log(arr);
```